# Find all users having specific number / string in a sql column

Tags: mysql, database

I've a db table named "users" which has a column named "alerts". The alert column has the comma separated data in following sequence;

```
UserA -> 2314|1,2315|1,2316|3
UserB -> 4235|2,2315|1,2314|3
UserC -> 342|5,2314|1,2316|3
```

Where if I split the comma and then slash separated value then;

```
2314 = pid
1 = uid
```

If I want to search all users having specific pid e.g. 2314 and to list them OR fetch them all, how and what SQL query I should have to use?

Comment: You could try using `WHERE field LIKE '$value|%' OR field LIKE '%,$value|%'` but **it would be the best to normalize your table.**

Comment: You seem to have dug yourself into a pretty bad hole with that table structure. If you can change the structure that should be your priority otherwise you are not taking advantage of a relational databese.

Comment: You could try what @Prix has said, but in the long run you are in for some terrible performance issues if this table gets loaded up.  I would suggest reorganizing your schema and using proper columns that can be indexed and sorted properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the face of it, you would search for `',2314|'`, but the problem is that numbers at the start of the value don't have a preceding comma.

There are 3 ways to solve it.

Handle the start case and middle case separately:

```
select * from users
where alerts like '2314|%'
or alerts like '%,2314|%'
```

Combine the cases by adding a comma to the beginning of the value to make it look like a middle case:

```
select * from users
where concat(',', alerts) like '%,2314|%'
```

Use a regular expression to combine the cases:

```
select * from users
where alerts rlike '(^|,)2314\|'
```

---

It would be better to redesign your tables to break out a new table to handle the many-to-many relationship you have shoehorned into one column.